# Why did the changes not apply in the output?

Tags: python, excel

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook


def find(wb, string):
    res = []
    for ws in wb:
        for row in ws.values:
            for value in row:
                if value is not None and string in str(value):
                    res.append(value)
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wb = load_workbook("C:\po2.xlsx")
    ws = wb.active
    values = find(wb, "MAN279")  # Replace findme with the string to find

    for value in values:
        ws.append([value])
    wb.save("Book1.xlsx")
```

So basically my code executed successfully but did not apply the changes to the excel file.

Comment: Are you missing some indentation after the if statement?

Comment: The code ran fine and created a new file Book1.xlsx with same data (all worksheets copied over) and the words were updated in the worksheet that was active.